# how to use nodejs crypto aes-256-cbc to encrypt text larger its block size

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption

I am using nodejs crypto module ( aes-256-cbc ) to perform encryption, I am encrypting strings, but it seems every time I try to encode a string with more 32 characters, it just encrypts the first 32 and spits out gibberish for the remaining part of the input text. I saw sth about partial encryption, slicing the text into [ 2  * BLOCK_SIZE ] and encrypting sequentially. I just need an implementation that can encode and decode a text like this - " This is is a kind of text that my implementaion will spit out partial gibberish for "

Here is my current implementation:

```html
var {
  generateKeyPairSync,
  randomBytes,
  createCipheriv,
  createDecipheriv,
  createHash,
} = require("crypto");
var config = require("../../config");
var { hkdfKeygen } = require("./hashing");


function encryptAes(message, key) {
  try {
    const encryption_key_buffer = hkdfKeygen(
      key,
      config.hkdfSalt,
      config.hkdfAdditionalInfo,
      32
    );
    const initialization_vector_buffer = randomBytes(16);
    const cipher = createCipheriv(
      AES_ALGORITHM,
      encryption_key_buffer,
      initialization_vector_buffer
    );

    let encrypted = cipher.update(message);
    encrypted += cipher.final("hex");

    return {
      encrypted,
      iv: initialization_vector_buffer.toString("hex"),
    };
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error("Error encrypting in AES -> " + err.message);
  }
}

function decryptAes(ciphertext, key, iv) {
  try {
    const encryption_key_buffer = hkdfKeygen(
      key,
      config.hkdfSalt,
      config.hkdfAdditionalInfo,
      32
    );
    const initialization_vector_buffer = Buffer.from(iv, "hex");

    const decipher = createDecipheriv(
      AES_ALGORITHM,
      encryption_key_buffer,
      initialization_vector_buffer
    );

    let decrypted = decipher.update(ciphertext, "hex", "utf-8");
    decrypted += decipher.final("utf8");

    return decrypted;
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error("Error decrypting in AES -> " + err.message);
  }
}
```

Comment: In `encrytAes()` in the `update()` call the input/output encodings are missing, it must be `cipher.update(message, "utf-8", "hex")`.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I don't think that matters according to nodejs crypto docs. Strings are utf-8 by default. Anyways, I just resolved it using the cipher's stream API, apparently I didn't look enough.

Comment: Still waiting for an explanation on why the implementation above doesn't work though.

Comment: Of course it matters. Just output the ciphertext. The front part is Latin1 encoded, the last part hex encoded, i.e. the ciphertext is corrupted. You have to specify the output encoding (regarding input it is not mandatory but cleaner).

Comment: I will try it out and see how it goes. 